# TypeError: Invalid connection Details (PG-Promise)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, pg-promise

So I'm trying to solve an issue that PG-Promise is giving me, but I'm not entirely certain as to why. I'm very certain that I set up the database and environment for it correctly, and have properly seeded and tested the database locally. If needed be, I can link the respective queries I have that make calls to the database, but I'm not sure if that'll help solve this.

That said, below is the pg-promise environment and the exact error it's firing. I appreciate any help with solving this!

```
const promise = require('bluebird');
promise object has .catch/,then etc..

const options = {
promiseLib: promise
};

const pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);

const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
```

my .env's database url is the following: DATABASE_URL=postgres://localhost:5432/project3//

```
const db = pgp(connectionString);

db.connect()
.then(obj => {
obj.done();
})
.catch(error => {
console.log('ERROR:', error.message || error);
});



TypeError: Invalid connection details.
at inst (/Users/benjidurden/Documents/projects/mighty-shelf-36224/node_modules/pg-promise/lib/main.js:177:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/benjidurden/Documents/projects/mighty-shelf-36224/routes/queries2.js:12:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/benjidurden/Documents/projects/mighty-shelf-36224/routes/index.js:4:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just look at [the code](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/lib/main.js#L177), then it is obvious that your `process.env.DATABASE_URL` is either `null` or an empty string, neither of which is a valid connection string, hence the error.

> my .env's database url is the following: DATABASE_URL=postgres://localhost:5432/project3

You presume so, but I'm betting that it is not.

**UPDATE**

Following this question, I have refactored the initialization errors in [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), to include the details of what is in fact being passed in, available from `v5.7.2`.

Comment: Why is it throwing this error, even when I specify a connection string? Like I specified my connection string with the following `code`const connectionString = ('postgres://localhost:5432/project3');`code`

Comment: @BenjiDurden if you specify a non-empty connection string, it won't throw such an error. It is possible something else is wrong in your code that you do not show here, otherwise it should work.

Comment: gotcha man! thanks! PG-Promise is incredible, don't get me wrong, but I just was unsure of what I was doing. I'll double check and figure it out! Thanks!

Comment: @BenjiDurden See the **UPDATE** added ;)